# function using .slideUp doesn't animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

ok first thing the function -

```
//function to change page   
function changePage(newPage) {
    $('.current').slideUp();
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(newPage).addClass('current');
    $('h3.title').text('');
    $('.slider_container').empty();
    $(newPage).slideDown();
}
```

how its called

```
$('.specialistLink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#footerLinks').removeClass('hide');
    $('header').css({'border-bottom': '10px solid #738c1f'});
    changePage("#page3");
    $('h3.title').text('dp-specialist').css({'color' : '#738c1f'}); 
    $('#page3 .left ul a:first').click();
    $('#footerLinks .left').css({'background-color':'#738c1f'});
    $('#footerLinks .right').css({'background-color':'#c8c0b5'});
});
```

Dom element for the above click event

```
<a href="#" class="specialistLink">
<div class="left">
  <h3>dp-specialist ></h3>
</div>
</a>
```

dom element to show/animate (minus the content for space reasons)

```
<section id="page3" class="hide">
</section>
```

Now the problem - I have 2 links like this that are identical (except #page to load, css values to change and the class that triggers the click), however this one never animates - it displays just fine (the content changes and #page3 shows) but the current #page does not slide up and the new one doesn't slide in except if #page3 is currently in view already in which case it does slide in.

Comment: I wonder if toggling the "current" class changes styles that effectively disable the animation

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: The key point here is that this function is run from a total of 6 different places within the document - all of them work as expected except this one link

Comment: also current class has no styles attached it's simply used as an identifier for this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe using a callback function for the slideUp will fix your problem (not sure, though):

```
function changePage(newPage) {
    $('.current').slideUp('slow',function() {
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(newPage).addClass('current');
        $('h3.title').text('');
        $('.slider_container').empty();
        $(newPage).slideDown();
    });

}
```

This will execute all that stuff inside the second function once the slideUp animation is complete

Comment: sort of worked however the click event doesn't wait for the function after the animation to complete before continuing

Comment: This seems to work ok but that one click event always animates faster than the rest...

 
function changePage(newPage) {
 $('.current').slideUp('slow', function(){
  $(newPage).slideDown();
 }); 
 $('.current').removeClass('current');
 $(newPage).addClass('current');
    $('h3.title').text('');
}

Comment: Can you move all those .css and .removeClass ecc from the click event into the slideUp callback?

Answer (score 0):

See if adding the current class after the animation is done will help out.

```
//$(newPage).addClass('current');
$('h3.title').text('');
$('.slider_container').empty();
$(newPage).slideDown(400, function(){ $(this).addClass("current"); } );
```